# What is the scale of prediction from models using the poisson family?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

If I have the model:

```
m = glm(x~y,family=poisson)
```

What is the scale on which the predictions are obtained (from, e.g. `predict(m)`)? For example, I know that if `family=binomial`, the prediction scale is log-odds.

Comment: Just to be sure, you do know about `predict(m,type="response")`, right?

Comment: The default link should be $\log(\cdot)$, I believe.

Comment: When the link function is unspecified the default link will generally be the canonical link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default predictions will be of log-rates.